# Export from Blender to Photoshop with same camera angle

Tags: export, camera, units, collada

I want to export 3d model from Blender to Photoshop - with same angle and position of camera. I exported as collada and obj, but when I import them in Photoshop, camera is not in same position. How can I export it, to get exactly same scene in Photoshop, as in Blender? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photoshop has its own camera. We cannot import the Blender camera position.

But, you made me think of a solution:

Select the object and so the camera. Make a parent<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

Select just the camera.

Go to front view <kbd>1</kbd>.

Now go to **View** > **Align View** > **Align Active Camera to View**.

The camera now has the same position as Photoshop camera and the object has the same view because it is parented to the camera.

Once exported, the object can be opened in Photoshop as you see it in Blender. More or less.

Remember to undo the changes you made in Blender.

Answer (score 0):

I have never done an export to Photoshop, but in other applications the mess up is because Blender uses Z as the vertical axis while the other application uses the X or Y axis as the vertical. The exporter may have an option to automatically adjust for that. I'm not sure if that is the problem or not. Scale can also be a problem.